# Asking about transit visa traveling from Nigeria to Canada with a Canadian passport

Tags: visas, canada, canadian-citizens, england, nigeria

Does a Canadian passport holder need a transit visa for a London transit when traveling from Nigeria to Toronto, Canada?

Comment: The other question has almost nothing in common with this one and is therefore not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

If you can enter a country, you can generally transit there without worrying about the destination and all other complex rules for transit (which only apply to people who cannot enter the country without visa).

Since Canadian citizens [can enter the UK](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/canada/tourism) for tourism and other purposes, they can also [transit there without visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/canada/transit).